# interface design for allowing custom parameter struct, falling back on defaults

Tags: c++, interface

Right now I have an awkward setup, but don't really know what the cleaner solution would look like. The parameter struct is defining the action keys for a simple fly camera. Right now it looks like this:

```
struct FlyCameraKeyParams {
    virtual int flyForwardKey() const = 0;
    virtual int flyBackwardKey() const = 0;
    // ... and others ...
};

struct FlyCameraDefaultKeyParams : public FlyCameraKeyParams {
    virtual int flyForwardKey() const override { return 'W'; }
    virtual int flyBackwardKey() const override { return 'S'; }
    // ...
};
```

The question is how to most conveniently allow this to be specified. I don't think it makes much sense to allow switching the control keys mid execution, so I'm leaning toward a template. But that feels unnecessary. Currently, though, I have this ridiculous pointer bool approach:

```
class FlyCamera {
public:
    FlyCamera(/* position, gaze, etc params */,
              FlyCameraKeyParams *keyParams = nullptr,
              bool deleteKeyParams = true) {
        if (!keyParams) {
            mKeyParams = new FlyCameraDefaultKeyParams();
            mDeleteKeyParams = true;
        }
        else {
            mDeleteKeyParams = deleteKeyParams;
        }
    }

    virtual ~FlyCamera() {
        if (mKeyParams && mDeleteKeyParams) delete mKeyParams;
    }

protected:
    FlyCameraKeyParams *mKeyParams = nullptr;
    bool mDeleteKeyParams = true;
};
```

In theory the user could just issue a `new CustomKeyParams()` in the construction of the `FlyCamera` and forget about it, and if they really need to own the memory then they could by setting the boolean at the end to `false`. But there's no reason for this, so should I just do:

```
template <class KeyParams = FlyCameraDefaultKeyParams>
class FlyCamera {
public:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<FlyCameraKeyParams, KeyParams>::value,
                  "Template parameter KeyParams must inherit from FlyCameraKeyParams");

    FlyCamera(/* no key params arg here */) {
        mKeyParams = new KeyParams();
    }

    virtual ~FlyCamera() {
        if (mKeyParams) delete mKeyParams;
    }

protected:
    FlyCameraKeyParams *mKeyParams = nullptr;
};
```

I want to allow users to e.g. implement using the actual arrow keys if they don't want to use WASD. Are there any cleaner alternatives that come to mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your primary problem right now is *memory management* — you're worried about how to use dynamic memory allocation without leaks or double-frees. C++ has a solution for that!

```
class FlyCamera {
public:
    FlyCamera(/* position, gaze, etc params */,
              std::unique_ptr<FlyCameraKeyParams> keyParams = nullptr) {
        if (keyParams == nullptr) {
            keyParams = std::make_unique<FlyCameraDefaultKeyParams>();
        }
        mKeyParams = std::move(keyParams);  // take ownership
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<FlyCameraKeyParams> mKeyParams = nullptr;
};
```

The destructor of `unique_ptr<T>` takes care of calling `delete` on the owned pointer (which will call the proper derived-class destructor as long as you've made the base-class destructor `virtual`).

---

However, for this particular problem, I don't see why you want a whole polymorphic class for `FlyCameraKeyParams`. Have you considered flattening things out into a more "C-like" style?

The name of the class should tip you off: I understand a desire for generic `KeyBindings` or something; but if your `FlyCameraKeyParams` are literally nothing more than `Params` to the `FlyCamera`, then you should *make* them params to the `FlyCamera`. Parameterizing the behavior of a concrete class is generally done by setting member variables.

Bonus: `FlyCameraDefaultKeyParams` describes the *defaults* of the key params of `FlyCamera`. So with C++11 member-variable-default-initializer syntax, we flatten that class away as well.

```
class FlyCamera {
public:
    FlyCamera(/* position, gaze, etc params */) { ... }

    void setFlyForwardKey(int k) { mFlyForwardKey = k; }
    void setFlyBackwardKey(int k) { mFlyBackwardKey = k; }

private:
    int mFlyForwardKey = 'W'; // Self-documenting defaults!
    int mFlyBackwardKey = 'S';
    // ... 
};
```

---

Notice in passing that I removed your virtual destructor from `FlyCamera` and made the `protected` members `private`, just to discourage people from inheriting from it. If you really *need* to allow inheritance, go ahead and put the virtual stuff back.

Comment: Excellent answer all around, thank you!  Yes, `std::unique_ptr` would definitely make sense.  However, I think I agree more with going back to flattening it back out.  This was actually the original implementation and I got rid of it because it felt cluttered, but in reality the "decluttering" just makes it more obtuse